# Removing space in Java error

Tags: java, csv

Basically, my program will convert data into .CSV format. But, I am faced with an error such that when I open my file in excel, it displays my data normally but when in notepad, it becomes some characters `㈬㥙〳㈬㥙ㄳ㌬かㄹ㌬か㌹㌬ㅋㄳ㌬ㅋ㈳㌬ㅋ㌳㌬ㅋ㐳`

Here's my line of code

```
String resultString = stringWriter.toString();
for ( String cheese: pie.keySet() ) {
    resultString += System.getProperty("line.separator") + cheese + "," + 
    pie.get(cheese).toString();

    resultString = resultString.replaceAll(",$" , "").replaceAll(" ", "");
}

this.WriteToFile(resultString);
```

I have multiple file with this method to remove the space but only this file has the error. I've tried multiple methods such as removing it before the first `resultString` and at the back of `pie.get(cheese).toString()`.

Also tried with `.replace(" ", "");` and `replaceAll("\\s","")`

Comment: I don't think notepad really deals well with non-standard encodings. Try an alternative that can do that perhaps.

Comment: @Dragondraikk as this is a program for users who require to use the file opened in notepad so there isn't really a choice to use to use other program.

Comment: looks like an encoding issue. Do you use the same encoding, when writing the file and opening it with notepad++?

Comment: how are you writing data in file? are you using proper encoding of the file? try something like `new FileOutputStream("outfilename"), "UTF-8")`

Comment: What does `this.WriteToFile(...)` do exactly? Can you please post the code of that?

Comment: @duffy356 i'm sorry but i don't quite get what you mean. But all my files are almost standard set of codes but the error occur in this file and only right after i use the `.replaceAll(" ", "");`

Comment: @mhlz it just prints out the file, which shares no relevance to the error. It happens when I add `.replaceAll(" " , "");`

Comment: So, just to be clear, if you remove the replaceAll(" ", "") call everything prints correctly (except for having too many spaces of course)?

Comment: @mhlz yes, thats right. Its a requirement to remove all the space.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that your input might not be UTF-8. Where do you get the keys from? Maybe they contain invalid UTF-8 sequences that get split incorrectly? One thing is for sure: somewhere on the way from your input to your output you got the encoding wrong. Where is hard to say without having more code.

Answer (score 0):

The data contains special characters. These characters are not rendered properly with default encoding. So When you are writing/creating a text/csv file, also set the character encoding to UTF-8. You can do this in JAVA Program itself.

Comment: Care to share how do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    String utf8String=getFromSource();
    File fileDir = new File("c:\\temp\\test.txt");

    Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));

    out.append(utf8String).append("\r\n");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```